# the_excerpt and the_content filters

Tags: wordpress

I'm in a kind of a bind. I'm adding rating to posts in WP. It's done with `the_content` filter. Thing is, some themes use excerpt instead of content in, say, archive loops. Adding rating to that is as simple as just adding filter for `the_excerpt`. Problem is, when excerpt is retrieved by theme, it fires `the_content` filter too (so rating is actually added), but after that, content is stripped off all html tags, so rating as it is (shapes) is gone but vote counter remains. This leads to non pretty situation like this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering what's the good way around it? I don't think there is a way to see list of actions which will call action handler for the current post (so that if action handler is called from `the_content` filter (check by `current_filter()`) and there is `the_excerpt` in 'queue' for this post just return content without changes) or a way to know to know if `the_content` was fired by function to retrieve excerpt. Of course, very dirty and horrible workaround would be to check content for vote counter text when action handler is fired by `the_excerpt` and just replace it with empty string but that's not a good solution. Am I missing something here? Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the cleanest solution I could come up with is this

```
function remove_mah_filter($content)
{
    if (has_filter( 'the_content', 'your_filter' ))
    {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'your_filter' ); // if this filter got priority different from 10 (default), you need to specify it
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'remove_mah_filter', 9); //priority needs to be lower than that of wp_trim_excerpt, which has priority of 10. Otherwise, it will still be triggered for the first post in the loop. 

// add it back so that it can be called by the actual content
function readd_mah_filter($content)
{
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'your_filter' ); // if this filter got priority different from 10 (default), you need to specify it
    return $content;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'readd_mah_filter', 11); //priority needs to be higher than that of wp_trim_excerpt, which has priority of 10.
```